# Paste lo last row in table

Tags: excel, vba, macos

thanks to help on here and google I almost have the macro i need... one issue is I want to paste values rather than copy...

I have set torange as a range DIM but when I test it via the msgbox it is blank which causes the paste to error...

```
Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, wsf.Columns("D:R"))
    
'If MsfT_LastRow = 2 Then
'VisRange.Copy Destination:=wst.Range("a2")
'Else
'MsfT_LastRow = MsfT_LastRow + 1

If MsfT_LastRow = 2 Then
    Set torange = Range("A2")
    MsgBox (torange)
Else
    Set torange = Range("a" & MsfT_LastRow + 1)
    MsgBox (torange)
    'VisRange.Copy Destination:=wst.Cells(MsfT_LastRow, 1)
End If
   
VisRange.Copy
Range(torange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your torange is empty because the cell you're trying to paste to should be empty. Since your torange is already a Range object, Range(torange) is  the error causer, so instead of:

```
Range(torange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Go with:

```
torange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Specify which sheet you're looking at or VBA will assume it's the active one:

```
With dws 'or whatever you called your worksheet variable
    If MsfT_LastRow = 2 Then 
        Set torange = .Range("A2")
        'MsgBox (torange) 
    Else 
        Set torange = .Range("a" & MsfT_LastRow + 1) 
        'MsgBox (torange)
    End If    
End With
    VisRange.Copy
    torange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: this did work but it copied to the wrong table... i tried ListObjects(tblMSFT).torange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues but get error

Comment: Specify the destination sheet instead of the table, i.e. in your case it'll likely still be dws, see my edit.

Comment: Also, you should start accepting the correct answers on your questions, you haven't on a single one so far. It helps other users find the correct answer quickly and people trying to help to skip the answered questions.

Comment: thanks sorry I wasn't aware the accepting answers I will go back and look at how I do it

Comment: this is overwriting the source file...  I tried adding WITH to both the copy and paste statement but is still pastes to the Source sheet not the to sheet?

Comment: Use it like I have it in my answer and only change dws if it's different from your to-sheet variable.

Comment: thanks for you help ... much appreciated

Comment: Glad it works now :)